# Виртуальный микрофон Linux, ALSA

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

Появилась необходимость запустить программу с закрытым исходным кодом, которая требует 4 микрофона для запуска, но подключен только один. Необходимо создать 3 виртуальных микрофона. Желательно обойтись средствами ALSA. ОС - Raspbian buster.

Comment: воспользуйтесь strace или аналогом, и выясните, чего же именно требуется этой вашей программе.

Comment: Программа вылетает с ошибкой: 1 микрофон не равен 4.